# Sqlite3.c with cppsqlite3 wrapper on c++ with encrypted database on windows

Tags: c++, sqlite, openssl, cppsqlite

i am trying to compile a project using sqlite3 amalgamation on a c++ project with the help of CppSQLite3 wrapper. I added SQLITE_HAS_CODEC flag because i have an encrypted database. I added openSSL 1.0.2 include directory and the libeay32.lib. 
I tried compiling with Clang 5.0 and GCC 4.9 on windows x86 and this is the error on the **linker**:

```
error : undefined reference to 'sqlite3CodecGetKey'
error : undefined reference to 'sqlite3_rekey_v2'
error : undefined reference to 'sqlite3_key_v2'
clang.exe : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks

Comment: " the extensions needed to read and write an encrypted database file are licensed software. " from the source: The code to implement this API is not available in the public release of SQLite. int sqlite3_key... Do you have the licensed extension?

Comment: No, is it SQLCipher? Because i was using an old version of sqlite3 amalgamation before which require only openSSL. Nothing else.